# Link from one page to choose value in dropdown on another classic ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am trying to get some links on one page of an old ASP website to redirect to a contact form that will then select the value in a dropdown list based on the link that was clicked from the page before it.

So if the user chooses `Send Inquiry` to `Agent P`, I want the contact form dropdown value to be `Agent P`, then they can fill out the rest of the form and on submit it will send an email to `Agent P` (the email part is already set up).

```
<div class="agentProfile">
<img src="images/agents/Agent-P.jpg" alt="Agent P" width="125" height="141" />
<h2>Agent P</h2>
<h3>Platypus</h3>
<ul class="contactList floatLeft">
<li class="mobile">xxx-xxx-xxxx</li>
<li class="email"><a href="hidden mailto link"></a></li>
<li class="email"><a href="/contact2.asp">Send Inquiry</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="agent_p.asp" class="profileBtn">View Profile</a>
</div>
```

That code will send the inquiry to the contact form. I'm not sure if I should have an anchor tag or something on the link sending the visitor to the contact form or how this is supposed to work.

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdainfo"><strong>What agent would you like to send this to?</strong></td>
    <td><select name="agent" id="agent" class="inputselect">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Agent P">Agent P</option>
    <option value="Agent Z">Agent Z</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

Can someone help me? I'm assuming that I will need Javascript for actions like this, but I'm not even close to an expert in Javascript so I'm lost on this.

Comment: Do you have any Classic ASP development experience?

Comment: No I was never trained in it. When I started working at my current job a couple years ago they kind of just threw stuff at me and told me to figure it out. Most of the time I do .NET

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want something like `<a href="/contact2.asp?agent=P">Send Inquiry</a>` then in your other page check the value of `<%= Request.QueryString("agent") %>` You can use an `If` or `Select` statement to check for different values being passed in the querystring variable. However if you have no experience with development in Classic ASP I'd suggest you at least look at some getting started articles or a beginners guide. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking into articles but wasn't having any luck with my specific situation. I'll keep looking to see if there is a site that can help me learn this stuff quicker. :)

Comment: To force the dropdown to the required agent using `?agent=P` technique you can do something like this in your contact page `<option value="P" <% If Request.QueryString("agent") = "P" Then %> selected="selected"<% End If %>>Agent P</option>` and so on...

Comment: @Lankymart can you put that solution in an answer? I used it and it works. :)

Comment: To be honest it's no different to the [answer already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24804627/692942) by [@James](http://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james), the approach is the exactly the same, I'd just accept that rather then posting duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1.  When the link is clicked, tell contact2.asp which agent was selected.

```
<li class="email"><a href="/contact2.asp?agent=AgentP">Send Inquiry</a></li>
```

Step 2.  In contact2.asp, preselect the selected agent in the dropdown

```
<select name="agent" id="agent" class="inputselect">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Agent P"<% 
  If Request.QueryString("agent") = "AgentP" Then Response.Write(" selected")
%>>Agent P</option>
<option value="Agent Z"<% 
  If Request.QueryString("agent") = "AgentZ" Then Response.Write(" selected")
%>>Agent Z</option>
</select>
```